# How to duplicate Core Data Object

Tags: nsmanagedobject

Hey guys I have run into a little problem.  In my core data model I have an object, lets call it object A.  Object A has a one to one relationship with another object, Object B.  Now Object C also has a one to one relationship with Object B.  So Object A and B have a one to one relationship with the same Object B.  Basically in code I have

```
Object B = (Code to create Object B)
A.b = Object B
C.b = A.b
```

This works absolutely fine with no problems.  My problem is that when I delete object A object b also gets deleted so when I call C.b = A.b my program crashes.  How can i delete Object A but preserve object B.

So far I have tried changing the delete rules to deny but I am not sure where to put the deny in the relationship.  I also tried making a copy of Object B but doing C.b = [A.b copy] but that just crashes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of the Core Data programming guide that refers to deletion: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1

It looks like you want to set object A's relationship with B as "nullify", so that the relationship from B to A gets removed, but the object still exists.

Bear in mind though, that nullify can create orphans if you are not careful.